# Unable to find my mistake in the process of solving a seemingly simple integration problem

Tags: integration

I am solving the following integration problem. I got two results when I followed two different methods. But I know one is wrong, but I am not sure where my mistake is. I request someone to help me find the mistake.

$$\int \frac{{\mathrm d}x}{e^x+4e^{-x}}$$

---

**Solution 1: (Incorrect)**

$$\int \frac{{\mathrm d}x}{e^x+4e^{-x}}=\int \frac{{\mathrm d}x}{e^x(1+4e^{-2x})}=\int \frac{{e^{-x}\mathrm d}x}{(1+4e^{-2x})}=\int \frac{{e^{-x}\mathrm d}x}{1+\left (2e^{-x}\right )^2}$$
Substituting $u=2e^{-x}$, we obtain ${\mathrm d}u = -2e^{-x}{\mathrm d}x$, and hence we can write

$$\int \frac{{\mathrm d}x}{e^x+4e^{-x}}=\int \frac{{e^{-x}\mathrm d}x}{1+\left (2e^{-x}\right )^2}=-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{{-2e^{-x}\mathrm d}x}{1+\left (2e^{-x}\right )^2}=-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{{\mathrm d}u}{1+u^2}=-\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(u\right)+C$$
$$\int \frac{{\mathrm d}x}{e^x+4e^{-x}}=-\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(2e^{-x}\right)+C=-\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{e^{x}}\right)+C$$

---

**Solution 2: (Correct)**

$$\int \frac{{\mathrm d}x}{e^x+4e^{-x}}=\int \frac{{\mathrm d}x}{4e^{-x}\left ( \frac{e^{2x}}{4}+1 \right )}=\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{e^{x}{\mathrm d}x}{ \frac{e^{2x}}{4}+1 }=\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{e^{x}{\mathrm d}x}{\left ( \frac{e^{x}}{2}\right )^2+1 }$$
Substituting $u=\frac{1}{2}e^{x}$, we obtain ${\mathrm d}u = \frac{1}{2}e^{x}{\mathrm d}x$, and hence we can write

$$\int \frac{{\mathrm d}x}{e^x+4e^{-x}}=\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{e^{x}{\mathrm d}x}{\left ( \frac{e^{x}}{2}\right )^2+1 }=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{{\left( \frac{e^{x}}{2} \right)\mathrm d}x}{\left ( \frac{e^{x}}{2}\right )^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{{\mathrm d}u}{u^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(u\right)+C$$
$$\int \frac{{\mathrm d}x}{e^x+4e^{-x}}=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{x}}{2}\right)+C$$

Comment: Did you mean $\tan^{-1}$ in place of $\tan$?  Trusting that you did, note that $\tan^{-1}(z)+\tan^{-1}\left(\frac 1z\right)$ is a constant.  (well, it's singular at $z=0$, but constant on both half-lines).

Comment: @lulu In which case the two solutions are the same, because the variable parts differ only by a constant.

Comment: @RobertShore  Absolutely.

Comment: @lulu What about the negative sign?

Comment: What do you mean?  Your two solutions differ by an additive constant, so both are correct.  Note that you really want to stay in one half line or the other, to avoid the singularity.

Comment: @lulu, I understood now. Thank you.

Comment: @lulu, Yes it is $\tan^{-1}$. I updated it.

Comment: And, just to stress, $e^z>0$ for all real $z$, so the problem of the singularity does not arise in your original integral.

Comment: @lulu, Sure, Do you want  to write the answer? So that I can mark it solved.

Comment: The following graph demonstrate @lulu 's argument

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qtq2d6bqhv

Comment: You did all the work.  Feel free to write up the full answer yourself, I'll review it once it is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that one solution is incorrect is false. Both the solutions are correct.

From the comments to the question given by @lulu and @RobertShore makes it clear that exploiting the fact $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{x}$ is a constant, we can conclude both solutions are correct.

Further, it is easy to visualize through the following plot showing both the solutions. First solution is blue, Second solution is Red.
[image: Graph showing both the solutions]